# How can I use a StatisticFormula Class from asp.net framework 4.8 in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is there any way I can use [StatisticFormula Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.statisticformula?view=netframework-4.8#moniker-applies-to) that is present in asp.net 4.8 in asp.net core 3.1 project? What are the options that we have in such scenarios?

Comment: Decompile it and then recompile it to target .NET Standard or .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, as can be seen at the bottom of the MSDN page you linked, which lists supported versions, which do not include any non-Framework versions of .NET.